# Concurrent modification of data

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to concurrently write to different parts of an image from different threads - My attempt at a multithreaded approach to rendering the mandelbrot set. I *know* that each thread will be writing to different pixels (no crossover) so that it is safe to do so. But I'm stuck with how to share the mutable image buffer across the threads without using a mutex (because that would defeat the purpose of having multithreading).

I am using the `image` crate for the ImageBuffer.
My current code is this:

```rust
/// Generates an RGB image of the specified fractal, with given
/// dimensions, and a defined transformation from the image coordinate
/// plane to the complex plane, and the max_iterations is the amount
/// of detail (50-100 being low, >=1000 being high, default 100)
pub fn generate_fractal_image(&self, fractal_type: FractalType, dimensions: (u32, u32), transform: &PlaneTransform<f64>, max_iterations: Option<u32>) -> RgbImage {
    let (width, height) = dimensions;

    let mut img = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
    let transform = transform.clone();

    for (_, row) in img.enumerate_rows_mut() {
        self.thread_pool.assign_job(move || {
            for (_, (x, y, pixel)) in row.enumerate() {
                let rgb = match fractal_type {
                    FractalType::MandelbrotSet => mandelbrot::calculate_pixel(x, y, &transform, max_iterations),
                    FractalType::JuliaSet => julia::calculate_pixel(x, y, &transform, max_iterations)
                };
                *pixel = image::Rgb([rgb.r as u8, rgb.g as u8, rgb.b as u8]);
            }
        });
    }

    img
}
```

And I get these errors:

```
error[E0597]: `img` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:38:20
   |
38 |             for (_, row) in img.enumerate_rows_mut() {
   |                             ^^^---------------------
   |                             |
   |                             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                             argument requires that `img` is borrowed for `'static`
...
52 |         }
   |         - `img` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `img` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:51:4
   |
38 |             for (_, row) in img.enumerate_rows_mut() {
   |                             ------------------------
   |                             |
   |                             borrow of `img` occurs here
   |                             argument requires that `img` is borrowed for `'static`
...
51 |             img
   |             ^^^ move out of `img` occurs here
```

That makes sense, but I'm stuck as to how to share img between the threads.

I'm using a thread pool implementation based off of [this chapter](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch20-04-storing-threads.html).

Still fairly new to rust so I'm definitely not doing things in necessarily the best way, or the "correct" way, so anything you can point out would be brilliant :)

Comment: Hi william, what you are looking for is actually "interior mutability".  It's a complex topic, however start with that as the search term.  There is also the rayon crate that will help you in your ability to do parallel processing across the image data. Don't try to do threadpool implementation yourself, as it's a complex process in its own right.

Comment: This seems like a textbook perfect use case for a crate like [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/). One of its main features allows you to split work on an array into multiple threads using `arr.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, x)| ...)` which automatically creates a and manages a thread pool, all you need to do is set `*x` to the right value. In your case, perhaps something like `img.as_flat_samples_mut().as_mut_slice()` is the array you're looking for.

Comment: If you still want to manage threads manually, then maybe `arr.split_at_mut(idx)` is your friend.